# Place boolean function in if statement expression

Tags: vb6, preferences

I'm maintaining a VB6 app.  For boolean functions, the original authors store the return value in a boolean variable before checking the result in an If Statement.  I prefer to place the function directly in the If Statement.  Is this a matter of preference or am I missing a potential pitfall in my style?

**Original Author Style**

```
bReturn = IsThisFun(maintainingVb6)
If bReturn = True Then
    'You haven't used .NET
Else
    'blah
End If
```

**My Style**

```
If IsThisFun(maintainingVb6) Then
    'You haven't used .NET
Else
    'blah
End If
```

I'm not sure if there is a proper terminology for these different approaches which may have allowed me to miss a previous post on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for affirming that this is a matter of preference.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: +1 for your entertaining example code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do whatever is most readable and maintainable. In my opinion, your style meets that criteria 98% of the time.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the original author created a variable to be able to debug the application. He would put a breakpoint at line 2, and will see the value of `bReturn` by hovering on it. But since you can also hover on equal symbol or put two breakpoints inside If/EndIf statement, there is no need to create a variable just for this.

By the way, I partially agree with DOK. There is no need to create unnecessary variables. It's not at all a waste of resources, because compiler is clever enough to remove this variable, but creating a variable such this does not make a code more readable.

Comment: I think this is probably likely explanation.  Hadn't though of that.  Now I see some lines commented out where they were were writing the values out to a text file.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, it's a matter of style.

The rule of thumb is: what's more readable.  Yours is probably to be preferred, because his code is redundant and most people prefer to remove redundancy. (The least he could do is remove the `= True`, which is totally redundant.)

If the boolean was a result of a longer function call, where the `If Then` was getting in the way, I would make the result a separate variable to make seeing the function call easier, but that's just me.

Comment: If you think "= True" is bad, try "If False = IsNull(blah) Then" rather than using "Not IsNull" or making a function called IsNotNull()

Answer (score 3):

There's one possible pitfall in using either method (w/ or wo/ variable). You have to certain that the function returns an actual VB Boolean (an OLE VARIANTBOOL), not a C bool or any other type. If the function is written and exposed in all-VB6, this isn't an issue, but...

It's not uncommon to create Declares for external (usually API) functions that are prototyped as returning bool, using `As Boolean` for the return type. VB accepts that, but when a 'True' (from the function's POV) is returned it may be in an anomalous state: a VB 16-bit Boolean that contains the value 1, instead of the normal -1.

This can have strange follow-on effects, the most obvious being a test for `If Not MyFunction()`, which will compute `(Not 1)`, or -2, instead of `(Not -1)`, or 0, as expected. So you get the strange result of `Not(True) = True`

The best practice is to `Declare` external 'bool' functions `As Long` and `CBool()` the result.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info that's interesting.  There are some calls to API functions that are written in C, that may explain the original author's choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't ever like declaring unnecessary variables.
It's a waste of resources, and doesn't make the code more readable.
I much prefer your style.

Comment: I find the numerous bReturn, bRetVal, bReturnValue, bRVal distracting.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make a method that returns a type of bool instead?

Example:

```
public bool maintainingVB6()
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: In his example, IsThisFun does return a Boolean type (or so it appears).

Answer (score 0):

Actually most often than not this is not a matter of preferences. The separate local var matters if the code is wrapped in `On Error Resume Next`.

If `IsThisFun` bombs out then `bReturn` does not get assigned and usually ends up being false. so the condition is not satisfied. In the second snippet if `IsThisFun` raises an exception then the execution gets inside the `If` true block.

For overcoming this I've seen numerous "non-sense" snippets like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
...
If Not IsThisFun(maintainingVb6) Then
Else
    ...
End If
```